# Can't change CSS navigation bar height

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I have a navigation bar which works fine, but I want to add padding and a height to each link.
Whenever I do so, It make all the links except the first one taller than they are supposed to be. This does not work in Fiddle for some reason, so here is the code:
(CSS)

```
body {
overflow-x:hidden;
font:13px arial;
background-color:#171120;
margin:0;
}
nav {
height:100px;
width:100%;
padding:10px;
padding-top:30px;
background-image:url('nav_bg.png');
border-bottom: 3px solid #302342;
}
nav #header {
color:#FFFFFF;
font:bold 56px arial;
float:left;
}
nav ul {
float:right;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
margin-top:20px;
margin-right:180px;
overflow:hidden;
}
nav ul li {
float:left;
}
nav ul li a:link,a:visited {
display:block;
width:180px;
##################################If you add height or border or padding, the links become taller!
background-color:#333333;
text-align:center;
font:bold 26px arial;
color:#ffffff;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

(HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css"/>

<title>Testing...</title>
</head>

<body>
<nav>
<div id="header">Testing...</div>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</li>
<li><a href="#">Home</li>
<li><a href="#">Home</li>
<li><a href="#">Home</li>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Why can't I add height, padding or border on the links without them suddenly becoming taller?

Comment: How do you expect to add something that takes up height without making something taller? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Your `a` tags are never closed...

Comment: `nav ul li a:link,a:visited {`  - notice `a:visited` will target all `a` tags visted states  ;-)

Comment: Also: CSS comments look like this: `/* a comment */`

Comment: Oh thanks. Obviously I know that it should get taller, but it adds the bottom part of the link to the top, so if I add a `border-radius`, it will be curve at the top the wrong way. And, when I scroll over this top part, it acts as a whole seperate link.

Answer (score 1):

This is well know and annoying problem.

This can be solved using "box-sizing"

See [this link](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) for a tutorial

This explanation is very relevant:

"The box-sizing CSS3 property can do just this. The border-box value (as opposed to the content-box default) makes the final rendered box the declared width, and any border and padding cut inside the box. We can now safely declare our textarea to be of 100% width, including pixel-based padding and border, and accomplish out layout perfectly."